# show/hide div when same link is clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I have a link that when clicked displays a `<div>` which contains a `<form>`.
I would like to hide the `<div>` containing `<form>` when the link is clicked again and display it again when clicked. I have created a simple Jquery to hide the div. How can I implement it to show/hide when same link is clicked.

```
$("#customize").click(function(){
    $("#cust").hide('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To toggle visibilty, use [toggle()](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) :

```
$("#customize").click(function(){
    $("#cust").toggle('slow');
    return false;
});
```

Comment: oh.. I forgot the toggle function. Thanks .. :D